# Show that the sequence $I_n = \displaystyle\int_0^{\pi/2} \cos^n x dx$ is convergent to $\frac{\pi}{2}$.

Tags: calculus, integration, sequences-and-series, limits

I am given the sequence:

$$I_n = \int_0^{\pi/2} \cos^n x dx $$

and I have to show that this sequence is convergent to $\frac{\pi}{2}$. So I think I have to show that:

$$\lim_{n \to \infty} I_n = \frac{\pi}{2}$$

All I managed to show so far is that the sequence is decreasing, but I don't see how that would help. So how should I approach this?

Comment: This can't be true. For $n=1$ the integral is $1$, and for fixed $x$, the integrand is nonnegative and decreasing as as a function of $n$. So the sequence $I_n$ is decreasing, hence for all $n$ we have $I_n \leq I_1 = 1$.

Comment: This is called [Wallis' integral](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wallis%27_integrals). The Wikipedia article contains plenty of information.

Comment: Just use beta function the trigonometric version.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**hint**

For an $ \varepsilon >0 $, small enough, consider two integrals

$$\left|\int_0^{\varepsilon}\cos^n(x)\,dx\right|\le \varepsilon$$
and

$$\left|\int_{\varepsilon}^{\frac{\pi}{2}}\cos^n(x)\,dx\right|\le \left(\frac{\pi}{2}-\varepsilon\right)\cos^n(\varepsilon)$$

As pointed by @Bungo, the limit should be zero.

Comment: (+1) Although, the OP likely has something else in mind.

Answer (score 1):

I suppose that you need to remember the reduction formula
$$J_n=\int \cos^n(x)\,dx=\frac 1 n \cos^{n-1}(x)\sin(x)+\frac {n-1}n \int \cos^{n-2}(x)\,dx$$ (have a look [here](https://socratic.org/questions/how-do-you-find-the-integral-of-cos-n-x) for the proof).

Now, for the definite integrals
$$I_n=\int_0^{\frac \pi 2} \cos^n(x)\,dx$$ you just have
$$I_n=\frac {n-1}n I_{n-2} \qquad \text{with} \qquad I_0=\frac \pi 2\qquad \text{and} \qquad I_1=1$$ This generates the sequence
$$\left\{\frac{\pi }{2},1,\frac{\pi }{4},\frac{2}{3},\frac{3 \pi
   }{16},\frac{8}{15},\frac{5 \pi }{32},\frac{16}{35},\frac{35 \pi
   }{256},\frac{128}{315},\frac{63 \pi }{512},\cdots\right\}$$ which is in fact
$$I_n=\frac{\sqrt{\pi }}2 \frac{ \Gamma \left(\frac{n+1}{2}\right)}{ \Gamma
   \left(\frac{n+2}{2}\right)}$$

Using Stirling approximation for $\log(\Gamma(p))$ and continuing with Taylor series
$$\log\left(\frac{ \Gamma \left(\frac{n+1}{2}\right)}{ \Gamma
   \left(\frac{n+2}{2}\right)} \right)=\frac{1}{2} \log \left(\frac{2}{n}\right)-\frac{1}{4 n}+O\left(\frac{1}{n^3}\right)$$ $$ \frac{ \Gamma \left(\frac{n+1}{2}\right)}{ \Gamma\left(\frac{n+2}{2}\right)}=\sqrt{\frac{2}{n}}\,e^{-\frac{1}{4 n}}+O\left(\frac{1}{n^3}\right)$$

$$I_n \sim \sqrt{\frac{\pi }{2n}} e^{-\frac{1}{4 n}} \implies \lim_{n\to \infty } \, I_n =0$$ For example, $I_{10}=\frac{63 \pi }{512}\approx 0.386563$ while the above formula would give $\approx 0.386547$.